# Write contents of csv to .txt files with one file per row?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv in the following format:

```
0 | Hello
1 | Hi
2 | GoodDay
```

I need to copy each row to a text file, so output will be:

```
0.txt -> Hello
1.txt -> Hi
2.txt -> GoodDay
```

I try (edited):

```
df=pd.read_csv('result.csv')
for x in df.iterrows():
    pd.df([x[1][1]]).to_csv(str(x[1][0])+".txt", header=False, index=False)
```

I am using Python and Pandas.

Comment: Tags seem to match, choice of language and module looks good. But the code you tried is missing (you are already using Python and Pandas ... ;-). Please add to the question, so we can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert to `ndarray` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and then use [`tofile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html):

```
for row in df.values:
    #print row
    row[1:].tofile(str(row[0])+'.txt', sep="\t", format="%s")
```

Solution with [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""
0|Hello
1|Hi
2|GoodDay"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="|", header=None)
print (df)
   0        1
0  0    Hello
1  1       Hi
2  2  GoodDay

for row in df.values:
    #print row
    row[1:].tofile(str(row[0])+'.txt', sep="\t", format="%s")
```

EDIT:

Anbother solution with [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) and [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html), but it add empty row in each `txt` file:

```
for _, s in df.iterrows():
    s.iloc[1:].to_csv(str(s.iloc[0]) + '.txt', index=False, header=False)
```